# How to integrate servers Microsoft IIS 7 and Microsoft Active Directory (LDAP)?

Tags: iis, iis-7, active-directory, ldap

I have windows server 2008 with IIS 7.
There I have some Web Based application installed.
I want to integrate that server with customer's Active Directory Server in order to users be able to access the application with their domain accounts.

I know this is beginner question, but sorry I am not an expert and didn't do anything with LDAP before.
I read here instructions for some different authentication protocols https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc733010%28v=ws.10%29.aspx

But as I understood I should use **Integrated Windows Authentication** correct?
But when I open Authentication within the IIS sites (WebClient) I see only options:

```
Anynomymous
Basic
ASP.NET
Digest
Forms
Windows
```

Which option should I choose and where I populate LDAP path and the user who will have privileges to access the LDAP?
Please take into consideration that I am really beginner for this and don't have any help for this configuration.

Thank you in advance

Comment: The last is the one.

Comment: Hi Lex Li, OK and where I populate LDAP path that is the IP address of the customer's LDAP server ???

Comment: you have no place to set that up but to add this machine to that AD domain. If you cannot do so, well this becomes completely another question.

Comment: Is it done by AD administrators? We have WebClient application installed on Windows Server. In Scope of this project is to integrate with customer's LDAP so the users will be able to access application using Web Browsers. Please take my point of view. What we have  to do to finish this Project Task from the perspective of our Windows Server machine? Or what we must say to our customer they have to do in order to finish this project activity? Thanks